# Should I use an [NSManagedObject] as the data for a UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, core-data

Here's the scenario that I'm interested in:

1) I'm using CoreData to store my data for my app
2) I'm using a UITableView to show that data to my user

My question is whether or not I should use an [NSManagedObject] as the data for the UITableView.

Obviously it will work just fine to do it this way, but a part of make feel like it's not best practice to do this.  I could use a dictionary or an array or something else to store the data and then when it's time to save, I could save that array to CoreData.

Is there any reason that one of these approaches is better than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost certainly use `NSManagedObject`s as the data for your table view, if only to save yourself the hassle of transforming arrays and dictionaries into/from `NSManagedObject`s in order to save/load from CoreData.

If by `[NSManagedObject]` you mean an *array* of `NSManagedObject`s, that is certainly possible.  But best practice when using CoreData with `UITableView`s is to use an `NSFetchedResultsController`.  The two main advantages are:

1. Easy processing of table view sections.  Specify a `sectionNameKeyPath` and corresponding sort descriptor, and the FRC will determine which section each object should appear in, assigning objects to indexPaths accordingly.
2. Automatic processing of insert/update/deletes.  There is boilerplate code which will enable the FRC to update the table view whenever objects are added, amended or deleted.

One other advantage to using `NSManagedObject`s directly, rather than arrays and dictionaries, is memory management: `NSManagedObject`s are fetched as "faults" initially and their properties will be populated only as required, reducing memory requirement compared to arrays and dictionaries which would presumably have to be fully populated from the outset.

Comment: frak.  I've never even heard of NSFetchedRsultsController... there is a dearth of decent documentation on CoreData out there.  Thanks.

Comment: Mmm the sample Master-Detail app provided by Apple uses NSFetchedResultsController  and their docs describe its use https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html